# An Error in Creating Popup

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have created a popup. And that is working fine in Activity.
but when i use this popup in fragment than an exception is occur.
i can't understand ho to solve this.

ChangePasswordFragment.java

```
public class ChangePasswordFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,AllInOneAsyncTask.ServiceResultListener {

    private EditText changeCurrentPassword,changeNewPassword,retypeNewPassword;
    private Button btnUpdate;
    private View rootView;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private AlertDialog popuupDialog;
    private Handler messageHandler;
    private AppSharedPreference appSharedPreference;
    // flag for Internet connection status
    private Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    // Connection detector class
    private ConnectionDetector cd;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_change_password, container, false);

        // creating connection detector class instance
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity());

        // get Internet status
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        // check for Internet status
        if (isInternetPresent) {
            messageHandler = new Handler();
            appSharedPreference = AppSharedPreference.getInstance(getActivity());
            initView(rootView);
        } else {
            // Internet connection is not present
            // Ask user to connect to Internet
            AppUtil.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "No Internet Connection", "You don't have internet connection.", false);
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    private void initView(View view)
    {
        changeCurrentPassword=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.change_current_password);
        changeNewPassword=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.change_new_password);
        retypeNewPassword=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.retype_new_password);

        btnUpdate=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_update);

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn_update:

            // check for Internet status
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                progress.setMessage("Please Wait, It may take few seconds...");
                progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                progress.setIndeterminate(true);
                progress.show();
                messageHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        checkValidation();
                    }
                }, 3000);
            } else {
                // Internet connection is not present
                // Ask user to connect to Internet
                AppUtil.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "No Internet Connection", "You don't have internet connection.", false);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void callChangePasswordApi() {
        String string_changeCurrentPassword = changeCurrentPassword.getText().toString();
        String string_changeNewPassword = changeNewPassword.getText().toString();

        Map<String, String> param = null;
        try {
            param = new HashMap<String, String>();
            param.put("username", appSharedPreference.getUserName());
            param.put("trpass", appSharedPreference.getPassword());
            param.put("oldpassword", string_changeCurrentPassword);
            param.put("newpassword", string_changeNewPassword);
            param.put("action", "FORGOT_PASS");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String jobjstr = param.toString();
        Log.e("LOGINREQUESTTTTTTT", jobjstr);
        if (jobjstr != null) {

            AllInOneAsyncTask asyncTask = new AllInOneAsyncTask(getActivity());
            asyncTask.setServiceResultListener(this);
            asyncTask.setServiceType(Constants.SERVICE_TYPE_GET_PROFILE);
            asyncTask.execute(param);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void checkValidation()
    {
        String string_changeCurrentPassword = changeCurrentPassword.getText().toString();
        String string_changeNewPassword = changeNewPassword.getText().toString();
        String string_retypeNewPassword = retypeNewPassword.getText().toString();

        if(!string_changeCurrentPassword.matches("") && string_changeCurrentPassword.matches(appSharedPreference.getPassword()))
        {
            if(string_changeNewPassword.length() >= 6 )
            {
                if(!string_changeNewPassword.matches(string_changeCurrentPassword))
                {
                    if(string_retypeNewPassword.length() >= 6 && string_retypeNewPassword.matches(string_changeNewPassword))
                    {
                        callChangePasswordApi();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (progress != null || progress.isShowing())
                            progress.dismiss();
                        showChangePasswordRechargePopup(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.password_not_match));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (progress != null || progress.isShowing())
                        progress.dismiss();
                    showChangePasswordRechargePopup(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.password_match));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (progress != null || progress.isShowing())
                    progress.dismiss();
                showChangePasswordRechargePopup(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.wrong_password));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (progress != null || progress.isShowing())
                progress.dismiss();
            showChangePasswordRechargePopup(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.correct_password));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(String resultData, int requestType) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestType == Constants.SERVICE_TYPE_GET_PROFILE) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resultData);
                String status = obj.getString("Status");
                String message = obj.getString("Message");
                if (status.equals("1")) {
                    String string_changeNewPassword = changeNewPassword.getText().toString();
                    appSharedPreference.setPassword(string_changeNewPassword);
                    if (progress != null || progress.isShowing())
                        progress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
                else {
                    if (progress != null || progress.isShowing())
                        progress.dismiss();
                    showChangePasswordRechargePopup(getActivity(),message);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    public void showChangePasswordRechargePopup(final Context ctx, String message)
    {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
        TextView tvMessage = (TextView)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        Button btnOk = (Button)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        tvMessage.setText(message);
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                popuupDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        // create alert dialog
        popuupDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        popuupDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.popup_bg);
        // show it
        popuupDialog.show();
    }
}
```

popup.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_bg" >

    <com.webzone.allbillpay.ui.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        app:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Exception

```
05-27 16:12:08.536 29591-29591/com.webzone.allbillpay E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.webzone.allbillpay, PID: 29591
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:122)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.<init>(AppCompatDialog.java:48)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:92)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:882)
                                                                            at com.webzone.allbillpay.fragment.ChangePasswordFragment.showChangePasswordRechargePopup(ChangePasswordFragment.java:242)
                                                                            at com.webzone.allbillpay.fragment.ChangePasswordFragment.checkValidation(ChangePasswordFragment.java:192)
                                                                            at com.webzone.allbillpay.fragment.ChangePasswordFragment.access$000(ChangePasswordFragment.java:33)
                                                                            at com.webzone.allbillpay.fragment.ChangePasswordFragment$1.run(ChangePasswordFragment.java:109)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.webzone.allbillpay"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.webzone.allbillpay.application.AllBillPayApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.webzone.allbillpay.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.webzone.allbillpay.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.webzone.allbillpay.ForgetPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.webzone.allbillpay.ConfirmMobileRechargeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.webzone.allbillpay.ConfirmDTHRechargeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.webzone.allbillpay.ConfirmDatacardRechargeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary</item>

        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary_darker</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/iron</item>

        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_darker</item>
        <!--<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_darker</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Dark.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary_darker</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="EditTextStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:ems">10</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

please help if any one have solution for this.

Comment: what was the exception?

Comment: check my updated question.
@AbhishekPatel

Comment: please post your manifeast also,because exception related to theme

Comment: check it.
@AbhishekPatel

Answer (score 0):

change the theme

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and add in `menifest.xml`

Comment: i tried 
but then there is an error in my main Activity on this line.

 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: if you extend your `Activity` by `AppCompatAcityty` than access the action bar like `getSupportActionBar` instead getActionBar.